# CodeIgniter only executing default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

In CodeIgniter, on the server, if you copy the whole CodeIgniter folder into a test folder and execute it, only the default controller executes. For other pages it is showing a 404 page not found error. What might be the reason?

Comment: Change `base_url` in your config file

Comment: check the `.htaccess` and set according to root.

Comment: I have folder called test directly inside the server. Inside that i have application,system,index.php,.htaccess folders and files.                              The .htaccess files looks like this :                                                                                           RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: Please let me know if there are to be any changes.

Comment: You should show some code - not in your comments - properly formatted so people can understand whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `rewrite` module is enabled. If it is not, enable it.

In `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Can you please send me the complete .htaccess file content refering to mine.

Comment: If you are using wampserver, `wamp tray icon->apache->apache module->rewrite module`

Comment: Actually the problem is only when it goes online , not in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try url like

```
localhost/codeignitor/index.php/hike
```

`Codeignitor` is your root folder name and `hike` is your new controller

Comment: Actually the problem is only when it goes online , not in localhost.